# Video Player in React Native

Tags: react-native

Not able to make fully controllable video player in react native

I am trying this one. facing issue in the landscape mode, it's overlapping my content while doing into landscape mode.

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';
import { position } from 'native-base/lib/typescript/theme/styled-system';

const VidPlayer = () => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(null);
    const [fullScreen, setFullScreen] = useState(false)
    const ref = useRef();
    const format = second => {
        let mins = parseInt(second / 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        let secs = (Math.trunc(second) % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        return `${mins}:${secs}`;
    }

    const [height, setHeight] = useState('');
    const [width, setWidth] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setHeight(Dimensions.get('window').height);
        setWidth(Dimensions.get('window').width);
    })

    return (
        <View style={[styles.VideoContainer]}>
            <View style={styles.VideoInner}>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                        setClicked(true)
                    }} style={{ position: 'relative', width: fullScreen ? width : '100%', height: fullScreen ? height : '100%', marginTop: 0, }} >
                        <Video
                            source={require('../../assets/Video/default.mp4')}
                            resizeMode='cover'
                            ref={ref}
                            onProgress={(x) => {
                                setProgress(x)
                            }}
                            muted
                            paused={paused}
                            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: 8 }}
                        />
                        {clicked && <TouchableOpacity style={styles.InnerView} onPress={() => { setClicked(false) }}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    ref.current.seek(progress.currentTime - 10)
                                }}>
                                    <Image source={require('./Images/backward.png')} style={{ width: 20, height: 20, tintColor: 'white' }} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    setPaused(!paused)
                                }}>
                                    <Image source={paused ? require('./Images/play-button.png') : require('./Images/pause.png')} style={{ width: 20, height: 20, tintColor: 'white', marginLeft: 70 }} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    ref.current.seek(progress.currentTime + 10)
                                }}>
                                    <Image source={require('./Images/forward.png')} style={{ width: 20, height: 20, tintColor: 'white', marginLeft: 70 }} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', position: 'absolute', bottom: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20 }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{format(progress.currentTime)}</Text>
                                {/* <Slider
                            style={{ width: 200, height: 20 }}
                            minimumValue={0}
                            maximumValue={progress.seekableDuration}
                            minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
                            maximumTrackTintColor="#FFF"
                            onValueChange={(x) => {
                                ref.current.seek(x)
                            }}
                        /> */}
                                <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{format(progress.seekableDuration)}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', position: 'absolute', top: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20 }}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    if (fullScreen) {
                                        Orientation.lockToPortrait();
                                    } else {
                                        Orientation.lockToLandscape();

                                    }
                                    setFullScreen(!fullScreen)
                                }}>
                                    <Image style={{ width: 20, height: 20, tintColor: 'white' }} source={fullScreen ? require('./Images/minimize.png') : require('./Images/full-size.png')} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default VidPlayer

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    InnerView: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 8,

    },

    VideoContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 200,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
        borderRadius: 12,
        marginTop: 16,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',

        shadowColor: "#ccc",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 1,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.15,
        shadowRadius: 1.00,
        elevation: 20
    },
your text
    VideoInner: {
        padding: 8,
    },
})
```

Expecting a fully controllable custom video player in react native. I can able to seek video, play/pause video, make video into full screen.